# How to find the source directory of package downloaded via FetchContent?

Tags: cmake

I have multiple static libraries created in house that get linked into an image.

I want to use an external library that gets retrieved by using `FetchContent_Declare`.

```
proj
  /lib1
    CMakeList.txt
  /lib2
    CMakeList.txt
  /exe
    CMakeList.txt
  /external
    CMakeList.txt (FetchContent_Declare)
  /build
    /deps
      /externallib1 (auto generated)
  CMakeList.txt
```

I would like to use the following in /proj/CMakeList:

```
include_directories(externallib1/include)
```

But I don't know how to figure out the directory where the external library was actually downloaded?

Answer (score 15):

The FetchContent module provides primary two approaches for [populating the content](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FetchContent.html#populating-the-content) of the external package in your main CMake build:

- [`FetchContent_MakeAvailable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_makeavailable): The simpler, and often preferred approach
- [`FetchContent_GetProperties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_getproperties) and [`FetchContent_Populate`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_populate): An approach offering more precise control, allowing custom variables/policies

Whichever approach you use, the `<lcname>_SOURCE_DIR` variable for the package should be defined, which points to the top-level source directory of the download external package. In this case, `<lcname>` is the lower-case name of the package provided to one of the above commands.

CMake typically downloads the external package into your build directory here:

```
${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/<package-name>-src
```

but you can use the aforementioned `<lcname>_SOURCE_DIR` variable to reference this location.

For example, with `googletest`, one simple usage might look like this:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG        release-1.8.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
```

Consequently, the `googletest_SOURCE_DIR` variable will point to the top-level source directory of the downloaded `googletest` repository, and you can include the `googletest` headers using something like the following:

```
include_directories(${googletest_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest/include/gtest)
```