# Why does "#include <gtest/gtest.h>" fail even after having used "FetchContent_MakeAvailable" in my CMake file?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, clion

This is my first time attempting the Google Test API in C++ and one of my first experiences with CMake. If it's useful, I'm using CLion. My CMake file, shown below, should ostensibly allow for files to `#include <gtest/gtest.h>`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(chord)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        googletest
        URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -pthread")
add_executable(
    chord
    main.cpp
    src/node.h
    src/node.cpp
    src/log.h
    src/log.cpp
    src/sha1.h
    src/sha1.cpp
    src/messageParser.h
    src/messageParser.cpp
    src/fingerTable.h
    src/fingerTable.cpp
    src/key.h
    src/key.cpp)
include(GoogleTest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
    unitTests
    test/fingerTableTests.cc
    test/keyTests.cc
    test/logTests.cc
    test/messageParserTests.cc
    test/nodeTests.cc
    test/messageParserTests.cc
)
target_link_libraries(
    unitTests
    gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(unitTests)
```

However, when I attempt `#include <gtest/gtest.h>` from `main.cpp`, I receive the error `gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory`. Can someone pinpoint the error in my CMake file? Thanks and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Did you ever get passed this?

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out as well.  The answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311116/how-to-find-the-directory-of-package-downloaded-via-fetchcontent suggests that you need to manually use `include_directories(${googletest_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest/include/gtest)`. The `${googletest_SOURCE_DIR}` variable is set by `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`.  However the official documentation does not mention needing to do this.  In fact most of it seems to imply that it is not required.

Answer (score -1):

Try to also link `gtest`:

```
target_link_libraries(
    unitTests
    gtest_main
    gtest
)
```